# How to calculate memory quota, net bandwidth and cpu bandwidth limit in an account?

Tags: accounts, ram, bandwidth, resources

Suppose `account aaa` will have a total of `10 EOS` with `1 EOS` staked for `net bandwidth` and `1 EOS` staked for `cpu bandwidth`. And no other account will delegate resources to `account aaa`.

How can we determine beforehand the `memory quota`(in Kb), `net bandwidth` (in Kb) and `cpu bandwidth` (in ms) that `account aaa` will have once it's created ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by simply running `cleos get account youraccount`, also you can check it out in https://eosflare.io

Finally, if you want to have a better understanding about EOS RAM and Bandwith check my study here: https://steemit.com/eos/@leordev/eos-ram-and-bandwith-analysis-airdropping-steps-on-junglenet

I hope it helps you!